# AngularJS ngOptions select list behaves inconsistently in IE 9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, ng-options

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/304fj3jh/7/) hopefully demonstrates the problem I am facing with IE 9. I am roughly doing the same things I am doing in my real app. I have a list of stuff that I loop through using ngRepeat. Each item has a property that can be selected from a dropdown list which is rendered using ngOptions.

The problem in IE seems to be that selecting an item from the list jumps back to the previous item in the list. Chrome does not have this problem, the item selection is perfect. In the example, try selecting the value 'Imported' in the Fiddle - I could simply not do it in IE whereas it works perfectly in Chrome.
The only thing I can think of that could be a problem is the IDs for the dropdown which are currently just plain old string values like '20', '30' and '40'.

The code for ngOptions is
`<select class="form-control" id="selProc" data-ng-model="currentPlant.ProcType" data-my-dropdown='Plants' data-ng-options="plant.SpecialProcurement as  plant.Description for plant in Plants"></select>`

`currentPlant` here is the looped variable.

The dropdown values are the following array:
`var dropDownValues = [{
                Plant: '2150',
                SpecialProcurement: '20',
                Description: 'External'
            }, {
                Plant: '2150',
                SpecialProcurement: '30',
                Description: '3rd Party'
            }, {
                Plant: '2150',
                SpecialProcurement: '40',
                Description: 'Imported'
            }];`

These dropdown values get populated in a custom directive's link function. In my real app the list gets fetched using `$http.post()` and the result is assigned to the dropdown variable using `JSON.stringify`. Regardless of whether this is good practice or not, the problem still persists. If the problem is because of the `JSON.stringify`, I would be keen to know. I have tried replacing that with a regular array assignment but the result is the same.

I'm stumped. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle is in the question. Very first line. http://jsfiddle.net/304fj3jh/7/

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it... :-(

Comment: I've had a look at this, and I think its a visual bug in IE. Quick check, does this also happen in IE11. Second check, I've updated your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/304fj3jh/9/, does that seem to magically work?

Comment: Hi Clark Pan, thanks for that. I haven't checked in IE11 probably because the work mandate for me is to run in IE9 for now. Your updated fiddle does seem to have the same bug I had - I tried selecting the value 'Imported' and the value '3rd Party' remains selected. The underlying values are correct, I agree with that totally. So confused.